# Odds of rolling two dice with equal outcomes seem more common than I pictured

Tags: probability

After running this program several times i noticed that my y value is somewhere between 60-80 every single time.

I thought because 70^2 is 4900 that i would end up with my y value ending up around 1 each run through, but actually its about a 1 in 70 chance of the dice equaling each other.

So why is it that rolling 2 70 sided dice and having the results equal each other is not a 1/4900 chance, but rather a 1/70 chance? Heres the program...

```
x=0
y=0

while x < 4900

  random = rand(70)
  random2 = rand(70)

  puts " "
  puts random
  puts random2


  if random == random2
    puts "the numbers matched"
    y+=1
  end

  x+=1

if x == 4900
  puts " "
  puts y
end
end
```

Comment: You're trying to get the probability of having the same value on a 70 side dice, regardless of the value. The probability isn't 1 / 4900 (probability of having the same specific value, for example 5) but something like 70 / 4900 because you have 70 combinations.

Comment: The probability of two 70-sided dice showing the same value is 1/70. Think of it this way. Die #1 is thrown first and shows a value of `x`. Then the probability of die #2 also showing `x` is 1/70, regardless of the value of `x`. Formally, the probability of both dice showing the same value is P(d2=x|d1=x)P(d1=x) summed over x = 1..70 (P(d2=x|d1=x) being the conditional probability of d2=x given d1=x). Since P(d2=x|d1=x) = P(d2=x) because of independence, and P(d1=x) and P(d2=x) equal 1/70 for all x, the original expression reduces to 70*(1/70)*(1/70) = 1/70.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability theory, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4900 possible outcomes `(1,1), (1,2), (1,3) .. ,(70, 70)`

There are 70 outcomes that are suitable for your condition - `(1,1), (2,2) .. (70,70)`

So, the probability is  needed_outcomes/all_outcomes  = 70/4900 = 1/70 ~= 0.0142858
In test program number of tests is not connected to number of outcomes. Larger number of tests tends to show more accurate results (through in this case we don't program at all, but there is ruby tag in the question).

So, we can try this:

```
x=0
total_matches = 0.0
N = 1000000

while x < N
  random = rand(1..70)
  random2 = rand(1..70)
  total_matches += 1 if random == random2
  x += 1
end
puts total_matches/N
```

It gives something around 0.0142.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to estimate the probability of two thrown 70-sided dice showing the same value (which we know to be `(1.0/70).round(6) #=> 0.014286`) by simulating throws, you can assume one die always shows the same given value and repeatedly throw the second die only, counting the number of times it shows the assumed value of the first die, and then divide the count by the number of throws. (See my comment on the question.)

Suppose each die has sides labelled `0`, `1`,...,`69` and we assume the first die always shows a `0`. We can then simulate as follows:

```
def simulate(nbr_throws)
  nbr_throws.times.sum { rand(70) == 0 ? 1 : 0 }.fdiv(nbr_throws).round(6)
end

simulate(        100)  #=> 0.01 
simulate(      1_000)  #=> 0.016 
simulate(     10_000)  #=> 0.0151 
simulate(    100_000)  #=> 0.01358 
simulate(  1_000_000)  #=> 0.014305 
simulate( 10_000_000)  #=> 0.014282 
simulate(100_000_000)  #=> 0.014284
```

See [Kernel#rand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) and [Integer#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv). More generally, if each die had `n` sides, change `rand(70)` to `rand(n)`.